How to use a cable modem-router that has coax with ethernet connectivity?
I have a naïve question on using DOCSIS cable modem-router without a coax cable connectivity.
I have Netgear C7000 which only supports WAN using Coax cable and WAN over ethernet is not supported. Unfortunately, I don't have a coax cable connectivity and only have ethernet connectivity.
Is there a way I can convert ethernet to a coax using any media converter. I have tried MoCA adapter which doesn't work in my case as I need to convert ethernet to coax and the coax to be given as input to the router.
There is a way to make operate Netgear C7000 in LAN mode with ethernet connectivity. But my usecase is to enable the router with coax input.


Is there a way I can convert ethernet to a coax

Not easily - you'll require the very large and expensive equipment used by ISPs - CMTS, or Cable Modem Termination System.
I'm not aware of any "consumer" variants of upstream equipment for any of DOCSIS, GPON, xDSL, etc... These connections are all much more complex than basic Ethernet, and require a lot of configuration and domain knowledge.

There is a way to make operate Netgear C7000 in LAN mode with ethernet connectivity. But my usecase is to enable the router with coax input.

I suggest you find a friend who will let you attach potentially unsupported equipment to their cable line.

It will be significantly easier to buy a new router that has ethernet capability.
Alternatively, you could add a firewall between the ISP modem and the c7000 and use it as a switch/AP only. However, that won't be cheaper than a new router.
https://firewalla.com/collections/firewalla-products
https://opnsense.org/opnsense-20-7/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
